# Get current index in XPath nested iteration

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I need to iterate over a nested loop of 2 levels in XML using Xpath1.0.

While iterating, it should print element value, 'Y' if it is first element of second level and current index as a counter.

I am able to accomplish one of the things, but not both at the same time.
e.g. If I iterate on first loop and use position() it gives me the current index, but I am not able to identify if it is first element of second level or not. Similarly if I iterate over second loop, I dont get actual index, but get if it is first element using position()=1

I have attached a sample request and expected response.

```
<root>
    <level1>
        <level2>name1</level2>
        <level2>name2</level2>
    </level1>
    <level1>
        <level2>name3</level2>
        <level2>name4</level2>
        <level2>name5</level2>
    </level1>
    <level1>
        <level2>name6</level2>
        <level2>name7</level2>
    </level1>
</root>
```

The result should be something like this:

```
name1_Y_1
name2_N_2
name3_Y_3
name4_N_4
name5_N_5
name6_Y_6
name7_N_7
```

Here is the existing code:

```
<root>
    <xsl:for-each select="$Map-Data/root/level1/level2">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="position() = 1">
                <names>
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat(current(), '_Y_', position())"/>
                </names>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <names>
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat(current(), '_N_', position())"/>
                </names>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>
</root>
```

Comment: Please explain which language you are writing the "nested loops" and show us that code.

Comment: It is in Tibco BusinessWorks in XPath editor.

Comment: ... "and show us that code". I can only second Martin.

Comment: I have added the code now.

Comment: Just for your information, the programming language you are using is called XSLT - XPath is merely embedded into XSLT.

Comment: I can only use XPath statements and not write bare XSLT because of product limitation. XSLT gets embedded while the code is generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With XPath 2.0 you could do

```
//level2/concat(., if (not(preceding-sibling::*)) then '_Y' else '_N', '_', position())
```

With XPath 1.0 you will need to make sure you check the `preceding-sibling::*` when iterating over your `//level2` and make the string concatenation in your host language.

As the sample you have now shown uses XSLT I would do

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="root">
  <xsl:copy>
    <!-- <xsl:apply-templates select="$Map-Data/root/level1/level2"/> -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="level1/level2"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="level2[not(preceding-sibling::*)]">
  <names>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(., '_Y_', position())"/>
  </names>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="level2[preceding-sibling::*]">
  <names>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(., '_N_', position())"/>
  </names>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks Martin for your response, but I am not able to use preceding-sibling::* in XPath 1.0, the editor complains that * is unexpected.

Comment: You can't use the XPath 2.0 expression I posted in XSLT/XPath 1.0 but I have edited my answer and added an XSLT 1.0 stylesheet that checks `preceding-sibling::*`.

Comment: I can't use bare XSLT directly and XPath editor doesn't allow me to use preceding-sibling, is there any other way to accomplish this.

Comment: @AnkurJain can you explain more about what you mean when you say the XPath editor doesn't allow you to use preceding-sibling? It *should*.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why your approach doesn't work is that in the selection of:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/root/level1/level2">
```

you are selecting **all** `level2` elements as a single node-set - and only **one** member of the entire set can be at position #1.

OTOH, if you were to split your selection like this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/root/level1">
    <xsl:for-each select="level2">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="position() = 1">
                <names>
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat(current(), '_Y_', position())"/>
                </names>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <names>
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat(current(), '_N_', position())"/>
                </names>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

you would be processing a separate node-set for each `level1` element and thus achieve your goal of having an individual `level2` element at position #1 in each batch.

However, you cannot use the same position() function to number all elements consecutively, because it will restart at each `level1` change (that's how you get the Y/N thing to work). For this you must use another numbering mechanism, for example `xsl:number`:

```
<xsl:for-each select="root/level1">
    <xsl:for-each select="level2">
        <names>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="position() = 1">_Y_</xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>_N_</xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
            <xsl:number level="any"/>
        </names>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: I already mentioned in the problem statement that I am able to accomplish only one of the things at one time. Is there any other way then using preceding-sibling to get this result?

Comment: @AnkurJain Have you seen the edit I have added just a few seconds before your comment?

Comment: I see it now, but I can't add bare XSLT as I am using XPath editor. It doesn't allow me to add `xsl:number`.

Comment: Well, `<xsl:for-each>`, `<xsl:choose>` and `<xsl:value-of>` in your existing code *are* XSLT, not XPath - so that doesn't add up. In any case, if you cannot use  `<xsl:number>` nor `preceding-sibling` (which BTW is pure XPath) then I don't know how you can accomplish this.